# Stray character in Ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I'm using wordpress. I make a ajax call with jQuery, PHP echos out a JSON object, but the response I get in javascript has a "0" added to the end which makes decoding the json object fail.

PHP:

```
function newspaper_getpost() {
    $d = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'long');
    echo json_encode($d);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_newspaper_getpost', 'newspaper_getpost');
```

JS:

```
  $.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,{
        action : 'newspaper_getpost',
        postID : $(this).val()
        }, function(response) {
              console.log(response);
  });
```

Output:

```
{"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}0
```

I tried

```
echo substr( json_encode($d), 0, -1);
```

and got

```
{"foo":"bar","baz":"long"0
```

so I'm sure its not the PHP side. I could just drop the "0" off the end of the response, but I feel like something bigger is going on nd I don't want to do a cheap hack to make it work. JQuery 1.6.1 btw. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the last version of jQuery, or the *minor-major* version? Edit: try debug the response directly on Chrome Inspector or Firebug and see if you receive it from PHP or is a JS issue.

Comment: Does the vestigial `0` break your code? If not, I'd just leave it alone. It could be a browser quirk.

Comment: It looks like the error comes from something after add_action(). Additionally make sure that you're telling $.post that it'll be receiving json by completing the type parameter in the post function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's obvious there is a 0 completely unrelated to this javascript piece.  You can see that you chopped the last character off of the response and it removed the `}` but the 0 remains.  You need to look at the rest of your PHP/HTML as there is a stray character somewhere being output.

If you were to add exit(); right after the echo, you'd see the 0 go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function newspaper_getpost() {
    $d = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'long');
    die(json_encode($d));
}
add_action('wp_ajax_newspaper_getpost', 'newspaper_getpost');
```

Answer (score 0):

That means there is something echoing after/inside your `add_action('wp_ajax_newspaper_getpost', 'newspaper_getpost');` php code. Look for a print_r(), echo, or something similar.